# How to change color of text and stop when clicked the button with 4 times in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing basic javascript that allow user to click the button for changing the colour of text; but, when use clicked 4times , the button does not change colour.

Here is my code of changing color. I do not know how to stop with 4 times.

```js
status = 1;
function changeColour(){
  getText = document.getElementById("text");
  if(status==1) {
    getText.style.color = 'blue';
    status = 2;
  }else if(status==2) {
    getText.style.color = 'red';
    status = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id= "text" align = "center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
<button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
```

Thanks all

Comment: set a counter outside the changeColour to 0 and increment it in changeColour. Wrapp in an if statement.

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous. Do you want the text to stop changing colour starting  from the 4th click or do you want to skip the colour change every 4th click?

Comment: And do you want to get back to the original colour on the 4th click?

Comment: Another question : should we stop changing colour starting **from** or **after** the 4th click

Comment: Dear C.Champagne. Actually, I want to stop changing colour from 4th click.

Answer (score 1):

```
var status = 1;
var counter = 0;
function changeColour(){
    counter ++;
    if (counter < 4) {
     getText = document.getElementById("text");
     if(status==1) {
       getText.style.color = 'blue';
       status = 2;
     }else if(status==2) {
       getText.style.color = 'red';
       status = 1;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set a `counter` outside the function

```js
var status = 1;
var counter = 0;

function changeColour() {
  if (counter == 4)
    return;
  counter++;

  getText = document.getElementById("text");
  if (status == 1) {
    getText.style.color = 'blue';
    status = 2;
  } else if (status == 2) {
    getText.style.color = 'red';
    status = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="text" align="center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
  <button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nbr_clicks` variable to count the clicks and `max_clicks` to set max clicks allowed then add a condition in the start of your function :

```js
status = 1;
nbr_clicks = 0;
max_clicks = 4;

function changeColour(){
  if(nbr_clicks<max_clicks)
  {
    nbr_clicks++;

    getText = document.getElementById("text");
    if(status==1) {
      getText.style.color = 'blue';
      status = 2;
    }else if(status==2) {
      getText.style.color = 'red';
      status = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id= "text" align = "center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
<button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
```

Comment: You've 4 questions and no one is accepted.... please if the answer is what you looking for mark it as **[Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add counter.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script language= "javascript">
            var status = 1;
            var count = 0;
            function changeColour(){
                getText = document.getElementById("text");
                if(count<4){
                  if(status==1) {
                    getText.style.color = 'blue';
                    status = 2;
                  }else if(status==2) {
                    getText.style.color = 'red';
                    status = 1;
                  }
                  count++;
                }else{
                 alert("You already clicked 4 times.");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id= "text" align = "center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
        <button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the odd and even click by `%`  2 and increasing `status` ,also can check that 4 times click.

```
<script language= "javascript">
    status = 1;
    function changeColour(){
        getText = document.getElementById("text");
        if(status　% 2 != 0) {
            getText.style.color = 'blue';
            status++;
        }else if(status　==　4) {
            getText.style.color = '';
            status = 1;
        }
        else {
            getText.style.color = "red";
            status++;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you remove the colour on the fourth click?

Comment: He asked `when use clicked 4times , the button does not change colour.`

Comment: Precisely! `getText.style.color = '';` does change the colour once again. Furthermore your code doesn't work because you set the `status` to 1 on the 4th click  so the colour can still be changed afterwards.

Comment: He don't want to change color every 4th times clicked !! That is my answer .

Comment: I didn't understand the question that way and I admit that the question is rather ambiguous. Anyway, on the 4th click the text becomes black again and this is a colour change.

Answer (score 0):

```js
status = 1,clk = 0
function changeColour(){
      if(clk<4)clk++;
      else return;
  getText = document.getElementById("text");
  if(status==1) {
    getText.style.color = 'blue';
    status = 2;
  }else if(status==2) {
    getText.style.color = 'red';
    status = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id= "text" align = "center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
<button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
status = 0;
function changeColour(){
    getText = document.getElementById("text");
    if(status < 4) {
        getText.style.color = (getText.style.color==="blue")?'red':'blue';
        status = status++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't a bug but `color`variable is not used. I think it should be worth using this way `getText.style.color = (getText.style.color===color)?'red':color;`

Comment: Edited! removed the color variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a new working and shorter answer with `%`operator

```js
var counter = 1;
var MAX_CLICKS = 4;

function changeColour() {
  var textElem = document.getElementById("text");
  if (counter < MAX_CLICKS ) {
      textElem.style.color = (counter % 2)? 'blue' : 'red';
      counter++;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text" align="center"><b>Hello World</b></h1>
<button style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block" type="button" onclick="changeColour()">Click</button>
```